# MYSQL 5.6 não reconhece a query como deveria

Tags: sql-select, mysql

Saudações!

Estou construindo uma query para pegar todos os momentos em que o valor esteve em 0 em um determinado dia e a maior hora do dia anterior.

Os dados no meu banco, são semelhantes aos que coloquei no [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ab1926/4). Coluna de Time_Stamp e Valor.
Até o momento, construí esta query para realizar a consulta desejada:

```
    SELECT 
    T1.Time_stamp,
    CASE
        WHEN T2.Time_Stamp THEN T2.Time_Stamp
    END Time_stamp,
    CASE
        WHEN (T2.Valor = 0) THEN T2.Time_Stamp
        WHEN (T1.Valor = 0) THEN T1.Time_Stamp
    END AS T2
FROM
    (SELECT 
        Time_Stamp,
            Valor,
            @seq1:=@seq1 + 1 AS Seq
    FROM
        test, (SELECT @seq1:=0) r
    WHERE
        CAST(time_stamp AS DATE) = '2018-11-02'

    ORDER BY Time_Stamp DESC) T1
        LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        Time_Stamp, Valor, 
            @seq3:=@seq3 + 1 AS Seq
    FROM
        test, (SELECT @seq3:=0) r
    WHERE
        valor = 0.0  and CAST(time_stamp AS DATE) = '2018-11-01'
    ORDER BY TIME_STAMP DESC
    LIMIT 0,1) T2 
    ON T1.Seq = T2.Seq
WHERE
    T1.valor = 0
```

O motivo de eu estar escrevendo esta pergunta, é que esta mesma consulta não funciona no meu banco, mas funciona no SQL Fiddle. Gostaria de saber quais são os possíveis motivos e como contornar isso. Gostaria de saber também, se possível, alguma alternativa mais eficiente para alcançar o resultado desejado.

Desde já, grato.

Answer (score 0):

Acho que não precisa meter muita sub-query.

Pode utilizar UNION e dividir a sua query em duas, para você não ter que reinventar a roda

```sql
mysql> set @date = '2018-11-02';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> select * from test where valor = 0 
and (DATE(Time_Stamp) = @date) 
UNION ALL 
(SELECT * from test where valor = 0 
AND DATE(Time_Stamp) = @date - interval 1 day 
ORDER BY Time_Stamp DESC LIMIT 1);

+---------------------+-------+
| Time_Stamp          | valor |
+---------------------+-------+
| 2018-11-02 04:37:59 |     0 |
| 2018-11-02 04:07:59 |     0 |
| 2018-11-02 03:29:04 |     0 |
| 2018-11-01 23:36:40 |     0 |
+---------------------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.03 sec)
```